# Unable to Download Cloudera and CDH Repository

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am trying to download CM5 and CDH repository from **"http://archive.cloudera.com/"** but it is asking for credential. I have created my account in Cloudera site but that credential is not working for downloading CM5 and CDH. What credential do I need to use for downloading repo..
On cloudera website I found that "Effective Jan 31, 2021, **all Cloudera software requires a subscription."**
Can someone help me with downloading CM and CDH.  I am looking for free version of it.
Thanks